# How to select the latest date between two entries in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query and this returns two columns that are almost the same except for two columns it looks like this:

Entry 1: LOTNUM = TAOM7U034N, OPCODE = 8385, DATEADDED = 2015-09-04 05:19:00, DATERELEASED = 2015-09-09 15:41:00

Entry 2: LOTNUM = TAOM7U034N, OPCODE = 8385, DATEADDED = 2015-09-28 16:51:00, DATERELEASED = 2015-10-01 14:34:00

```
SELECT
    LOTNUM,
    OPCODE,
    DATERELEASED
FROM
    HOURLY_FT_WIP.CACHE_IRAC_HOLD_LOTS AS i
WHERE
    LOTNUM IN('TAOM7U034N')
AND DATEADDED =(
    SELECT
        MAX(DATEADDED)
    FROM
        HOURLY_FT_WIP.CACHE_IRAC_HOLD_LOTS x
    WHERE
        x.LOTNUM = i.LOTNUM
    AND x.OPCODE = i.OPCODE
)
```

This query is alright and returns the 2nd entry and that is what I needed. But this query takes 15 seconds.

I tried to modified to this:

```
SELECT
    LOTNUM,
    OPCODE,
    DATERELEASED
FROM
    HOURLY_FT_WIP.CACHE_IRAC_HOLD_LOTS AS i
WHERE
    LOTNUM IN('TAOM7U034N')
GROUP BY LOTNUM, OPCODE
```

This one is much faster like 0.05 seconds. However this returns the first entry which is the older date. I need the latest date which is the 2nd entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine with another field being included in the select, you could try something like this.

```
SELECT
    LOTNUM,
    OPCODE,
    DATERELEASED,
    MAX(DATEADDED)
FROM
    HOURLY_FT_WIP.CACHE_IRAC_HOLD_LOTS AS i
WHERE
    LOTNUM IN('TAOM7U034N')
```

Comment: This is nice. But still hoping there is still some answers.